# How would I duplicate the Rank function in a Sql Server Compact Edition SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-ce, analytic-functions

It doesn't look like SQL Server Compact Edition supports the RANK() function. (See  *Functions (SQL Server Compact Edition)* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077(SQL.90).aspx).

How would I duplicate the RANK() function in a *SQL Server Compact Edition* SELECT statement.

(Please use Northwind.sdf for any sample select statements, as it is the only one I can open with SQL Server 2005 Management Studio.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.[Product Name], x.[Unit Price], COUNT(y.[Unit Price]) Rank 
FROM Products x, Products y 
WHERE x.[Unit Price] < y.[Unit Price] or (x.[Unit Price]=y.[Unit Price] and x.[Product Name] = y.[Product Name]) 
GROUP BY x.[Product Name], x.[Unit Price] 
ORDER BY x.[Unit Price] DESC, x.[Product Name] DESC;
```

Solution modified from *Finding rank of the student -Sql Compact* at 
[Finding rank of the student -Sql Compact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887096/finding-rank-of-the-student-sql-compact)

Comment: +1: Well done, good find.  I updated my answer to include an ANSI-92 JOIN version; what you posted is ANSI-89 join syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  SELECT x.[Product Name], x.[Unit Price], COUNT(y.[Unit Price]) AS Rank 
    FROM Products x
    JOIN Products y ON x.[Unit Price] < y.[Unit Price] 
                  OR (    x.[Unit Price]=y.[Unit Price] 
                      AND x.[Product Name] = y.[Product Name]) 
GROUP BY x.[Product Name], x.[Unit Price] 
ORDER BY x.[Unit Price] DESC, x.[Product Name] DESC;
```

Previously:

```
SELECT y.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM TABLE x
        WHERE x.id <= y.id) AS rank
  FROM TABLE y
```

Comment: Not working. "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 9,Token in error = SELECT ]"